# SQL increment date using recursion

Tags: mysql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table which contains the following structure:

```
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| Number    | Date       | Subject   |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| 1         | 2015-01-01 | ABC       |
| 2         | 2015-01-01 | ABC       |
| 3         | 2015-01-01 | ABC       |
| 4         | 2015-01-01 | ABC       |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
```

I need to loop through the table and increment of *n* days each date.
So, assuming *n = 10* I should get this result:

```
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| Number    | Date       | Subject   |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| 1         | 2015-01-01 | ABC       |
| 2         | 2015-01-11 | ABC       |
| 3         | 2015-01-21 | ABC       |
| 4         | 2015-01-31 | ABC       |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
```

The problem is a bit more complicated because *n* is generated by using a function which needs the **previous generated date**
I am trying to use CTE to accomplish this with the following CTE, but I get too many rows than expected.

```
WITH myCte(Number, Date, Subject)
AS
(
   SELECT * FROM MyTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      Number, dbo.get_next_date(Date)
   FROM MyCte
)
SELECT * FROM MyCte
```

Comment: Are you looking to modify the table (UPDATE) or just return the information based on the `n` value suplpied?

Comment: This is a view, so I just need to return the resultset with the modified date.
Each resultset, order by Number, should have the date incremented using the previous value of that date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have no `WHERE` clause in the recursive CTE. This would cause the query to stop when `MAXRECURSION` value is reached (default 100).

Here is an example to set a limit with a `WHERE` clause

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
Number  int,
Dt      Date,
Sub   CHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
(1,'2015-01-01','ABC'),
(2,'2015-01-11','ABC'),
(3,'2015-01-21','ABC'),
(4,'2015-01-31','ABC') 



;WITH myCte(Number, Date, Subject)
AS
(
   SELECT * FROM @MyTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      Number, DATEADD(day, 10, Date),Subject
   FROM MyCte
   WHERE Date < GETDATE()
)
SELECT * FROM MyCte
```

EDIT - If you know the number of rows, then you could just use `TOP` and get those rows.

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM MyCte
```

Comment: By using your solution I get 4 rows from @MyTable and again 4 rows with the correct calculated date but they all have Number = 4

Comment: My answer was not a solution to your problem, but to demonstrate what your issue is. See edit in answer

Comment: I just applied a GROUP BY and a MAX(Date) to your solution and it works. Plus I change the where using n instead of Date

Comment: Cool. That was the intention of the response. Just to show that you need a `WHERE` clause.